# Deja vu meaning

Tags: meaning

If *deja vu* means *already seen or experienced*, what would you call *the feeling that you're experiencing something again, but in fact you haven't; it's just a strong, but false, feeling of familiarity?*

Comment: That is it. The definition of [Déjà vu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%C3%A9j%C3%A0_vu) - the phenomenon of having the strong sensation that an event or experience currently being experienced has been experienced in the past, whether it has actually happened or not.

Comment: What you describe **is** *a feeling of déjà vu.* [*Déjà vu*](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/déjà-vu) describes the false feeling.

Comment: @AndrewLeach I do not have to have a "feeling of déjà vu" - déjà vu is the name of the phenomenon

Comment: @mplungjan Maybe not, but the ODO definition uses "feeling of" and "sense of", and that's how I've heard it used.

Comment: But is it correct to use *deja vu* to define a mere repeat of experience?

Comment: No that is not correct. That is just "I did/saw it again" unless you speak French at the time

Comment: Then why exactly is Jasper Loy confusing me and getting voted up for it?

Comment: Because "the experience of thinking that you have already done something" is called *deja-vu*. It doesn't matter whether you **have** done it before or not.

Comment: Then what would you call the false feeling that you have done something before. False-deja vu? As pointed out by @Zibbobz

Comment: The actual feeling is and always would be called "deja-vu".  Its typical use is to describe a feeling of familiarity, outside of knowing whether or not you have actually performed the task before (and frequently used as-is to describe a feeling of familiarity for an unfamiliar task!).  My suggestion is, if you wish to differentiate between actually having done the task and not, to use "false deja-vu" to describe the feeling that you have done a thign before, when you actually have not.  This is only if it is necessary to differentiate the two, and usually such clarification is not needed.

Comment: Sometimes it is, in fact, necessary to differentiate. 
e.g. I was sitting with all my relatives at a family event. There was a sudden, sharp sense of familiarity about the whole setting -- the jokes being cracked, banters, the smiling faces... Perhaps something like this did happen 10 years ago because we had, in fact, come together at the same place earlier at a similar event -- a wedding. Perhaps it didn't. But i do need to know if I should call it a deja-vu or false deja-vu.

Comment: Didn't we have this question before???

Comment: @user52023 You call it deja-vu. There is no such thing as "false deja-vu". Whether you **feel** you have done something before does not depend on whether you have actually done it.

Comment: **I do not think that this question should be closed.** This is **not** a straight 'general reference' question. The comments above and the answers all show that the meaning/understanding of this phrase is not clear and that views differ. **Even the dictionaries do not agree on the exact meaning of the term.**

Comment: This list may have some relevance. http://listverse.com/2008/02/28/top-10-strange-phenomena-of-the-mind/

Comment: @RyeBread You realize, of course, that your comment is being upvoted by those of us who expanded the comments list to add that same comment, only to find you beat us to it? Why couldn't you have been quicker, and saved us the trouble?

Comment: Voted to reopen. As my answer shows - and as stated in my previous comment, **even the dictionaries do not agree on the exact meaning of the term**, and hence this is **not** a straight 'general reference' question.

Comment: If this indeed is GR, let there be a comment directing the OP to a definitive canonical answer that will also help future askers. Closing this post will only encourage future questions, on the premise that this question has never been satisfactorily answered.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That the phrase means "already seen" in French is irrelevant. In English there is no 'false' or 'true' sense of *déjà vu*. The phrase is used in English to designate the fleeting and imprecise sense that something (which you cannot name) about what you have just seen or heard is familiar, that there was something there which you have heard or seen before. It *feels* like a memory, but it's not attached to anything specific.

If you were able to pin the memory down sufficiently to be able to declare it false or true, it would not be a sense of *déjà vu*— it would be a *memory*. Memories can be false or true, but *déjà vu* is a *state*—it has no truth value.

ADDED:
TrevorD points out—and very thoroughly documents—a more literal sense of *déjà vu* which has become current. I think this arose as an ironic use of the phrase—*Does it feel like we've seen this before?*—but it may very well be that it is now innocent of that overtone and now means just *Here we go again*.

Comment: It is the best explanation of deja vu I have come across.

Comment: -1 I disagree to the extent that it *can* be used to refer to unwelcome repeat events as discussed in my answer below.

Comment: @TrevorD Very good point, which I've taken the liberty of appropriating.

Comment: @StoneyB. Your approach and answer seems most logical and appropriate to me, along with TrevorD's input. This completely answers my question. There may be other aspects that linguists might wish to discuss and argue upon. But for me, I've got the answer.

Answer (score 4):

Whether you actually experienced something or not, *deja vu* still applies.

Comment: The response is brief and exhaustive, voting up.

Comment: -1 I strongly disagree - see my answer.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that even authoritative dictionaries do not agree on whether proper use of the term ***deja vu*** is restricted to events that have **not** actually happened previously, as shown by the following definitions:

**Definitions restricted solely to events that have *not* actually happened previously:**

> the feeling or illusion that one has experienced something before although one is actually experiencing it for the first time.
>   [Chambers](http://www.chambers.co.uk/search.php?query=deja%20vu&title=21st)
>
> the experience of perceiving a new situation as if it had occurred before.
>   [Collins English Dictionary - accessed from Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/deja+vu)

**Ambiguous definitions referring only to events that have *not* actually happened previously (but with no explicit restriction):**

> the feeling that what is happening now has happened before in exactly the same way:
>   - *a strange sense of déjà vu*
>   [Longman English Dictionary Online](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/deja-vu)
>
> the feeling that you have previously experienced something which is happening to you now:
>   - *I had a strong sense of déjà vu as I entered the room.*
>   [Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/deja+vu)
>
> The strange sensation that something one is now experiencing has happened before:
>   *I knew I had never been in the house before, but as I walked up the staircase, I got a weird sense of déjà vu.*
>   [The American Heritage® New Dictionary of Cultural Literacy - accessed from Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/deja+vu)

**Definition explicitly *not restricted* to events that have not actually happened previously:**

> A feeling of having previously experienced something, especially when that is not the case.
>   - Have I done this before? Talk about déjà vu.
>   [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/deja_vu)

**Definitions referring both to events that have *not* actually happened previously, and to unwelcome repeat events**

> a feeling of having already experienced the present situation:
>   - *a feeling of déjà vu*
>   - *to list the opponents of his policies is to invite boredom and a sense of déjà vu*
>   [Oxford Dictionaries Online (ODO)](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/d%C3%A9j%C3%A0-vu?q=deja%20vu)
>
> the illusion of having previously experienced something actually being encountered for the first time.
>   disagreeable familiarity or sameness:
>   - *The new television season had a sense of déjà vu about it—the same old plots and characters with new names.*
>   [Based on the Random House Dictionary - accessed from Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/deja+vu)
>
> the illusion of remembering scenes and events when experienced for the first time:
>   a feeling that one has seen or heard something before:
>   - *I entered the room and immediately felt a sense of déjà vu.*
>   something overly or unpleasantly familiar *(chiefly US, informal)*:
>   - *When the car broke down again, it was déjà vu.*
>   - *The rise in housing costs is déjà vu all over again.*
>   [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/deja+vu) and [Merriam-Webster Learner's Dictionary](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/deja%20vu)

In my experience, and based on the above definitions, I would say that:

1. The primary meaning of the term is *the feeling or illusion that one has experienced something before although one is actually experiencing it for the first time.*
2. The term is also used to refer to a repeat of unwelcome past events: *something overly or unpleasantly familiar*; but I would also say that this meaning is not restricted to the US (as one of the definitions suggests), but is also a not uncommon British usage.
3. The term is **not** generally used to refer to **actual** repeat events, except in the sense of my previous bullet point.

#### Addendum

To address the comment from RegDwighт, breaking the question into two parts:

> If *deja vu* means *already seen or experienced*, ...

- *Deja vu* **does not** generally mean *already seen or experienced* - see paragraph 3. of my answer above - **except** when used (e.g. sarcastically) as described in my paragraph 2. above.

> ... what would you call *the feeling that you're experiencing something again, but in fact you haven't; it's just a strong, but false, feeling of familiarity?*

- **That** feeling **is** described as *deja vu* - see my paragraph 1. above.

Comment: So. What is your answer to the question at hand, then?

Comment: @RegDwighт I would have thought that was obvious from the summary at the end of my answer, but see the **Addendum**.

Answer (score 0):

Deja-vu is defined as the feeling you are doing something you have done before.

It is important to note that it is the *feeling* that what you are doing is something you've previously done.  Not, necessarily, that the feeling is of a thing you genuinely have done before.

Though if you want to differentiate the two, you could call it "false deja-vu", meaning your feeling is incorrect - you feel as though you have done it before, but that feeling is false.

Comment: This explanation logically makes more sense.

Answer (score 0):

In French "déjà vu" has two meanings.

- one has been imported into English :

"J'ai une impression étrange de déjà vu" = I have a strange feeling of having already seen something like that, perhaps in a dream".

- the other is strongly pejorative :

"Ses tableaux ? Il n'a rien inventé, rien que du déjà vu !" = About his paintings ? He has invented nothing, everything has been done before.